# Adding subquery to a grid query

Tags: sql, sqlite, grid, subquery

Following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610929/subtract-from-negative-numbers-in-column-to-use-in-sql-query), I have another query that I need to subtract a value of 10 from for all negative numbers in the data. Sadly, I'm just not sure how to implement the same subquery as is given in the previous question.

The query in question is

```
SELECT 10 * (c.customer_x / 10), 10 * (c.customer_y / 10),
COUNT(*) as num_orders,
SUM(o.order_total)
FROM t_customer c 
JOIN t_order o
ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_x / 10, c.customer_y / 10
ORDER BY SUM(o.order_total) DESC;
```

which calculates the order totals from each grid square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query doesn't change much in the query below.  The only difference is the new join and one more term added to the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT 10 * (c.customer_x / 10) AS col1,
       10 * (c.customer_y / 10) AS col2,
       COUNT(*) AS num_orders,
       SUM(o.order_total) AS order_total_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT customer_id,
           CASE WHEN customer_x < 0 THEN customer_x - 10 ELSE customer_x END AS customer_x,
           CASE WHEN customer_y < 0 THEN customer_y - 10 ELSE customer_y END AS customer_y
    FROM t_customer
) c
INNER JOIN t_order o
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_x / 10,
         c.customer_y / 10
ORDER BY SUM(o.order_total) DESC
```

Note that you *could* solve this without the use of the subquery which I have used.  However, the subquery makes it much more readable, and lets us compute the adjusted `customer_x` and `customer_y` values neatly.

Comment: I get the error `Error: no such column: t.customer_x`?

Comment: @DaveC Reload the page, I changed aliases to match what you used in your question above.

Comment: Perfect. I think it was SUM line which confused me. I kept putting it in the wrong place.